# C: Adding Exponentials

Tags: c, double, floating-accuracy, addition, exponential

What I thought was a trivial addition in standard C code compiled by GCC has confused me somewhat.

If I have a double called A and also a double called B, and A = a very small exponential say 1e-20 and B is a larger value for example 1e-5 - why does my double C which equals the summation A+B take on the dominant value B? I was hoping that when I specify to print to 25 decimal places I would get 1.00000000000000100000e-5.

Instead what I get is just 1.00000000000000000000e-5. Do I have to use long double or something else?

Very confused, and an easy question for most to answer I'm sure! Thanks for any guidance in advance.

Comment: "Do I have to use long double or something else?" Did you try it?

Comment: `1e-5 + 1e-20 => 1.0000000000000011e-5` If you print enough places, you should get the difference.

Comment: The two relevant digits in the difference are 15 spaces apart, which is near the end of the range that a `double` can express. Note that it makes no sense to print more than 17 decimal digits.

Comment: http://ideone.com/48qOmg

Comment: @Henrik: To be more exact, http://ideone.com/lQRu1K

Comment: @KerrekSB: Of course it makes sense to print 17 decimal digits, if you want to see the exact numeral a double represents and your print/convert routine supports that. Not everybody wants to approximate, to think in only decimal, and to discard information. It depends on the application.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I think I said "more than 17"...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Typo, I meant more than 17. It makes sense to print 53 digits, since that is what may be necessary to see the exact value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I think you're thinking of *binary* digits!

Comment: you can use hex if you care about exact values...

Comment: @KerrekSB: No, it requires 53 decimal digits to see the exact value of some double values, when using decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is not enough precision in the double mantissa. 2^53 (the precision of the double mantissa) is only slightly larger than 10^15 (the ratio between 10^20 and 10^5) so binary expansion and round off can easily squash small bits at the end.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Google is your friend etc.

Comment: yes, 9 x 10^15 - but still it is theoretically enough that - if it wasn't for binary expansions of decimals being recurring and round off errors then it should be fine

Answer (score -1):

Floating point variables can hold a bigger range of value than fixed point, however their precision on significant digit has limits.
You can represent very big or very small numbers but the precision is dependent on the number of significant digit.
If you try to make operation between numbers very far in terms of exponent used to express them, the ability to work with them depends on the ability to represent them with the same exponent.
In your case when you try to sum the two numbers, the smaller numbers is matched in exponent with the bigger one, resulting in a 0 because its significant digit is out of range.
You can learn more for example on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

Comment: For the case in question, accuracy of double *is* sufficient.